# Australian "stubby holder", is it understood in America or England?

Tags: word-request, word-meaning, australian-english

In Australia, I learned about the "stubby holder",
which is an isolating cylinder-shaped cover to place a 0.33l soda/beer can or bottle to keep it cool.

Looking up "stubby" I found:

> Having a short, stocky build; thickset.

Which kind of describes a can or even a bottle.

What would be a British English or American English equivalent for it? Or would "stubby holder" be understood?

In Portugal, we use "frapé" to keep 0.75l wine bottles cold, which translates with automatic tools to "frappé" (an ice-cold drink), which doesn't really mean the same.

| [image: Stubby holder] | [image: Portugues frapé] |
| --- | --- |
| Stubby holder | Portuguese frapé |

Comment: As a UK native I've heard [stubby](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stubby) often enough to know what it means, but I had to think for a moment to get [stubby holder](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stubby-holder). It would help to hear the spoken intonation to register it as a noun phrase (stubby isn't an adjective here).

Comment: I suggest "drinks holder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion arises because:

> 1. In standard English, 'stubby' is an **adjective** meaning 'short and thick'.

> 2. In casual or informal Australian English, 'stubby' can also be a **noun** meaning 'a small bottle of beer'.

So a 'stubby holder' in Australia is a holder for a small bottle of beer. Possibly they may be used for cans as well. I don't think many English people will immediately understand the term, and I think even fewer Americans.

[image]

Comment: I think it's the short 330ml can specifically.

Comment: What would be a British English or American English equivalent for it?

Comment: @WeatherVane - when my first wife came back from Australia in 1976, and we started dating, a 'stubby' was a bottle, typically 375 ml, but I guess now the march of progress may have led to the term being used for cans, although those were 'tinnies' as I recall. Says [one site](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/21-essential-australian-expressions): 'Australian expressions related to alcohol are many and varied. A tinny is a can, while a stubby is a little bottle.'

Comment: Oh, I thought a tinny was any can.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I _think_ it's just beer. It can also (in Oz) be a small aluminium-hulled boat, and in New Zealand be a a small package of cannabis wrapped in 'tin'  (aluminium) foil

Answer (score 3):

The American English version is a [beer koozie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koozie)/beer cozy. Cozy is used for insulating covers for various dishes or containers. Other examples include tea cozy, which is used to insulate a warm teapot, or a casserole dish cozy.

I have never heard “stubby holder” in the US.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've never heard about "Koozie" :). But English is not my first language...